# Does JVM or CLR use registers for running JIT'ed code?

Tags: jvm, clr, jit, cpu-registers

I understand that JVM and CLR were designed as stack-based virtual machines. When JIT compiles bytecode into native code, does it also translate stack primitives (load/store) to registers on X86 platform?

If yes, it looks like whether bytecode is stack-based or register-based doesn't really matter. JIT matters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that you are confusing two different concepts.

At least for Java, the JVM acts as a virtual machine - it's an idealized computing machine with a comparatively high-level assembly language (the bytecode) that is based on a call stack with stack frames.  When compiling Java into bytecode, the Java program is turned into (essentially) an assembly program for controlling this machine.

When actually running Java on a given system, the job of the JVM implementation is to faithfully simulate the execution of this stack-based machine using whatever hardware is actually available.  This typically means that a huge number of stack operations would be implemented using registers when possible, and perhaps using other specialized hardware that isn't present in the description of the Java virtual machine.  The actual details of how this is done is implementation-specific - some implementations might compile it down to machine code that does almost everything in registers, while a simpler implementation might just compile down to in-memory operations.  I worked for a few months on a JavaScript implementation of the JVM, in which case we "compiled" the code down to JS functions, which were in turn handed off to the browser's JS implementation.

The reason for this distinction is that Java was designed to be easily downloaded and embedded (think applets).  In this case, security and portability are important concerns.  The bytecode had to have some way to be inspected automatically to rule out certain types of malicious code (buffer overruns, for example).  Similarly, whatever format was used had to be sufficiently high-level that it could be run on a variety of different platforms (handheld devices, supercomputers, PCs, etc.)  The choice of the stack-based JVM made both of these concerns possible to satisfy simultaneously.  It's high-level enough that it's possible to inspect the bytecode to rule out many type errors or reads/writes of uninitialized memory, while sufficiently low-level that a JVM can use tricks like compiling down to code using registers.

If you are curious what **your particular** JVM will do to a specific piece of code, you should take a look at the documentation.  Most JVMs have some way of giving you information about how they're executing the code.  If your question is "why not just have bytecode do register-based manipulation," the reason is twofold:

1. There is an analog of registers in bytecode - each stack frame has some extra dedicated space for temporary values to be stored, and
2. There isn't as robust support for registers as is present in x86 or MIPS because the JVM code had to be easy to execute on multiple pieces of hardware, and hardcoding in a number of registers might complicate things.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to *not* use registers on an x86 core.  The processor doesn't have an instruction to, say, add two local variables.  One of them *has* to be loaded in a register. Then you can add the value in the register to the value in a variable.  And store the result back to a stack variable.

The optimization opportunities are obvious from this sequence.  Like *not* storing it back but keeping the result in a register and using it later, saving both the store and the load.  That's the job of the optimizer, it looks for ways to make the best use of the available registers.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to know for sure would be to examine JIT compiled output, but it's quite safe to say that using registers is one of the JIT compiler's lamest optimizations. I believe most programmers would be hard pressed to write faster code than the JIT compiler does.

The JIT compiler is capable of a lot, and probably uses registers as much as is appropriate. Things like method inlining encourage the use of registers, and a lot of imperative program code can be expressed more simply on a register-based architecture, so it only makes sense for the JIT compiler to use registers.

Comment: Note: This was written from the prepective of a C# dev, so it may be more applicable to CLR than JVM.